# Cannot create Aspect file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I'm trying to add an Aspect class to my Aspect Project. I get this error:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
class org.eclipse.ajdt.core.javaelements.AJCompilationUnit tried to access private field org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.parent (org.eclipse.ajdt.core.javaelements.AJCompilationUnit is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @9ae2810; org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @60eb5d5b)
```

I cannot open the *.aj files.

I've tried:

- Creating a new package -> same error.
- Adding simple Java classes and test them. They work without the *.aj files.
- Looking for answers online -> no working solution.
- Using Java 11 and Java 17.

My system:

- OSX 12.3.1. M1 chip.
- Eclipse Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)
- AspectJ 1.9

[image]

Comment: It seems AspectJ Development Tools (AJDT) does not yet work with the Java 17 with which you run your Eclipse. Java 16 and 17 are more restrictive than older Java version causing such issues. As far as I know, there is no Java 11 for M1 preventing you to run your Eclipse with Java 11. So you might use Eclipse macOS x86_64 running with Java 11 instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried with Java 11 but still get the same error.

Comment: Tried what exactly? Please show your error log starting with `!SESSION`.

Comment: AJDT works with Javca 17 and 18, you just need to install the [right version](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/master/docs/developer/IDE.md#eclipse). The AJDT version also needs to match the Eclipse version.

Comment: Oh that's you, Alexander! Thank you! I found that exact GH repo of yours last week and I was able to make it work. Would you mind posting this as an answer so I can mark this question as solved? You're a saviour!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJDT works with Java 17 and 18, you just need to install the right version. The AJDT version also needs to match the Eclipse version.

For more information, see the AspectJ quick guide about [setting up a development environment, section "Eclipse"](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/master/docs/developer/IDE.md#eclipse).